# Figure of speech name for interrupted word

Tags: figures-of-speech

Is there a name for the figure of speech where the speaker says part of a word then changes to a synonym to emphasize a point?

For example, "I have really been strug- working hard on this for a year." Sometimes there is an "um" or "I mean" between the partial word and the replacement. Also, I think it only happens with verbs.

What I've looked for so far:
I looked up Anapodoton, but that is for whole sentences interrupted, as in "When in Rome ..."

The Greek word for "word" is λέξη, so I looked up analegey, but Google would only show "analogy".

I also did the same thing with "verb" (ρήμα), but that shunted to anathema.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A, or rather B- its rhetorical effect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368349/a-or-rather-b-its-rhetorical-effect) 'It is well known, or rather notorious, that Tokyo is the Great Babylon of Japan.' Metanoia. Though I doubt you'll find a term defined narrowly enough to stipulate stopping to correct _mid-word_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **metanoia**. According to [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/metanoia-rhetoric-term-1691311):

> Metanoia is a rhetorical term for the act of self-correction in speech or writing. Also known as *correctio* or the *figure of afterthought*.

They give examples including:

> Kreuz Market is the ultimate barbecue restaurant—no, scratch that—barbecue *experience* in Central Texas (and therefore the world).

Comment: Perfect. Interestingly, Wikipedia has no article for that. There is one for Metanoia (Theology), but not for the figure of speech.